# Mount a windows path (cifs) in a voulme of a docker image

Tags: linux, mount, samba, docker, chown

I have a windows file server and an Ubuntu machine which runs docker. Inside this docker there is a Nextcloud container. The `/var/www/html` inside ther Nextcloud container is mounted as volume on the Linux host. Now I want the files saved in my cloud are saved directly on my file server. So I tried:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=user //192.168.1.100/files /var/lib/docker/volumes/interna_nextcloud/_data/data/User/files/
```

If I create a file on the host system in this directory, the file will be created on my fileserver. But I fail to create a file in the Nextcloud container. The owner of this directory is `root`. I tried to change it (on the host and on the container) with

```
chown www-data [...]/User/files
```

with no error code but also with no success, the owner stays `root`.

Is there a way to **mount** a **Windows Samba** directory inside a **docker container** with the **host** by docker volumes?  The **docker container does not have access to the file server network** (and should not have)